# Symfony 1.4, function create is not called anymore

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I created a form to allow people to register, it worked fine but weeks passed and it is not working anymore.

I have my module Inscription with index function:

```
public function executeIndex(sfWebRequest $request)
{
    $this->form = new InscriptionForm();
}
```

In indexSuccess.php, I have:

```
<?php include_partial('form', array('form' => $form)) ?>
```

My partial form is like:

```
<form action="<?php echo url_for('Inscription/'.($form->getObject()->isNew() ? 'create' : 'update').(!$form->getObject()->isNew() ? '?id='.$form->getObject()->getId() : '')) ?>" method="post" <?php $form->isMultipart() and print 'enctype="multipart/form-data" ' ?>>
... // All my input for the inscription Form
</form>
```

And the create function:

```
public function executeCreate(sfWebRequest $request)
  {
    $this->forward404Unless($request->isMethod(sfRequest::POST));

    $this->form = new InscriptionForm();

    $this->processForm($request, $this->form);
  }
```

My form is displayed properly, but if I submit the form, the create function is not called anymore.

```
$form->getObject()->isNew()
```

return true.

The update case works, just the create does not. I have no errors, just in config -> request, I have:

```
parameterHolder:
  action: index
  module: Inscription
```

Seems like my form call the action index instead of create. 
I'm searching for hours now and I can't get the reason why.

**Edit:**

I got this when I submit my form:

```
options:
  path_info_key: PATH_INFO
  path_info_array: SERVER
  http_port: null
  https_port: null
  default_format: null
  logging: '1'
  relative_url_root: null
  formats: { txt: text/plain, js: [application/javascript, application/x-javascript, text/javascript], css: text/css, json: [application/json, application/x-json], xml: [text/xml, application/xml, application/x-xml], rdf: application/rdf+xml, atom: application/atom+xml }
  no_script_name: false
parameterHolder:
  action: index
  module: Inscription
  sf_guard_user: { id: '', _csrf_token: 2a4bd03a7c7cb1cfd8a41653fddabcc3, username: '', email_address: admin, password: admin, password_confirmation: '', Informations: { sexe_id: '1', date_naissance: { month: '', day: '', year: '' }, id: '', token: '0', etat_id: '2' }, Avatar: { id: '', valide: '0' } }
attributeHolder:
  sf_route: 'sfRoute Object()'
```

This is like create function is not called!

And in my logs I have:

```
#   type    message
1    sfPatternRouting   Connect sfRoute "sf_guard_signin" (/guard/login)
2    sfPatternRouting   Connect sfRoute "sf_guard_signout" (/guard/logout)
3    sfPatternRouting   Match route "sf_guard_signin" (/:module) for /Inscription     with parameters array ( 'module' => 'Inscription', 'action' => 'index',)
4    sfFilterChain  Executing filter "sfRenderingFilter"
5    sfFilterChain  Executing filter "sfExecutionFilter"
6    InscriptionActions Call "InscriptionActions->executeIndex()"
7    sfPHPView  Set component "sf_twitter_bootstrap_permanent_slot" (/)
8    sfPHPView  Render "sf_app_dir\modules/Inscription/templates/indexSuccess.php"
9    sfPartialView  Render "sf_app_dir\modules/Inscription/templates/_form.php"
10   sfPHPView  Decorate content with "sf_app_dir\templates/layout.php"
11   sfPHPView  Render "sf_app_dir\templates/layout.php"
12   sfWebResponse  Send status "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"
13   sfWebResponse  Send header "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8"
```

Normally, when I submit my form, it checks for a value from an InscriptionForm, but I can set every value that I want; there is no control anymore and the index function calls the index again.

Comment: Do you have a route defined? Or using the default module/action?

Comment: Hi ! Yes i defined a route in my routing.yml :
    `inscription:`
      `class: sfDoctrineRouteCollection`
      `options:`
        `model:                Inscription`
        `module:               Inscription`
        `prefix_path:          /Inscription`
        `column:               id`
        `with_wildcard_routes: true`

Comment: Just to make sure - please check what value is rendered in "action" attribute in your form when the page is loaded in Index action.
Also could you post stack from "logs" section from debug toolbar? That would be helpfull.

Comment: Could you post the generated html of the form? The route when you submit goes to `/Inscription`, not `/Inscription/create` nor `/Inscription/update`

Comment: I posted answers Tomasz but it was deleted cause i post a non answer, but in comment i have 550 characters max so i can't post ... Where is the logic ?